# Object doesn't support this property or method error in Jquery

Tags: jquery, struts2

when i try to get the value from form attribute using jquery on Page load i am getting java script error as, ***"Object doesn't support this property or method."*** let me know the problem on this.

```
alert($("[name=searchAttribute.brand.attributeValue]").val());
```

I am using struts2 and Jquery.
Inside action i have searchAttribute as ValueObject attribute inside this i have brand as another and inside it it has attributeValue as another attribute.

I need to load the dropdown based on this value on page load.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
            function() {

            fetchDropDownValues($("#idGMMHouse").val(),'<s:property value="brandloadUrl"/>','idGMMBrand','idGMMLine');
            var fieldname = '';


                alert($("[name="+ 'searchAttribute.brand.attributeValue' +"]").val()); 

            });
</script>


<tr>
                    <td width="80px"><s:text name="filter.price.gmmhouse" /></td>
                    <td width="1px"><s:text name="filter.colon" /></td>
                    <td width="270px"> <s:select cssClass="drop" tabindex="1"
                        listKey="code" listValue="value" headerKey="0"
                        headerValue="Select One"
                        onchange="fetchDropDownValues(this.value,'%{brandloadUrl}','idGMMBrand','idGMMLine');" id="idGMMHouse"
                        name="searchAttribute.house.attributeValue" list="lstGMMHouse"></s:select></td>
                    <td width="80px"><s:text name="filter.price.gmmbrand" /></td>
                    <td width="1px"><s:text name="filter.colon" /></td>
                    <td width="160px"><s:url action="loadGMMLineDropDown"
                        id="lineloadUrl"></s:url><s:select cssClass="drop" tabindex="1"
                        id="idGMMBrand"
                        onchange="fetchDropDownValues(this.value,'%{lineloadUrl}','idGMMLine');"
                        headerKey="0" headerValue="Select One"
                        name="searchAttribute.brand.attributeValue" list="{}"></s:select></td>
                    <td width="80px"><s:text name="filter.brand.desc" /></td>
                    <td width="1px"><s:text name="filter.colon" /></td>
                    <td width="270px"><s:select cssClass="drop" tabindex="1"
                        id="idGMMLine" headerKey="0" headerValue="Select One"
                        name="searchAttribute.line.attributeValue" list="{}"></s:select></td>
                    <td align="LEFT">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: post your `html` and `js` code related to problem

Comment: can you try `$("input[type=select][name='searchAttribute.brand.attributeValue']")`?

Comment: Now the error went off when i put as alert($("[name='searchAttribute.brand.attributeValue']").val()); but i am not able to get the value. it is showing only 0.

Comment: Allow me to rephrase... please post your rendered HTML (from the browser, do "View Source Code"). jQuery doesn't deal with Struts (`s:select`) it deals with HTML (`select`).

Answer (score 0):

What version of jQuery are you using?  If it's 1.7.2, I think it no longer supports the [name=whatever] syntax.  I've been doing some SharePoint development with jQuery/Sharepoint, and having that issue when parsing xml with similar markup.  Try using `.filter()` method to do what you need instead.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's $ selector always returns an array of DOM elements, even if the selector itself matches just a single element. So you should iterate through those elements, or if you're sure that there's only one of them, then you can reference it by adding a [0] array index to your selector.

The val() function can only be interpreted on a single DOM element, not on an array.

So this

```
alert($("[name=searchAttribute.brand.attributeValue]")[0].val());
```

should fix your problem - of course you should check for the length of the array and make sure there is at least one element in it, before referencing the first element.

Comment: @AymanSafadi I have to admit this took me by surprise. Good to know, thanks.